# Xcode 11 Canvas cannot preview in this file

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am unable to preview my app in canvas.

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
NSLocalizedFailureReason=An application bundle was not found at the provided path., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to install the requested application}
```

This was the run diagnostics. Any solution? I am able still able to use the iOS simulator. Thanks

Comment: may be better to put your code that gets error

Comment: Well there's no code that causes the error because I started a new project and canvas still showing same error.

Comment: Try cleaning the build folder and click on `try again`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Xcode 11 couldn't detect a substantial change in the code for me. All I had to do was clear the build - `Product | Clear Build Folder` and then click on the `try again`.